# Copy constructor of linked list

Tags: c++

I am making a doubly linked list which only stores a single datatype(generic) and i need a copy constructor for it.I thought i had got it right but when i tested it using a file given by my instructor, it isn't working.When i try to debug it, the problem seems to be in constructor of linked list class in which I just set head=NULL.Is this a correct constructor

```
//this is the struct i am using
struct ListItem 
{
    T value;
    ListItem<T> *next;
    ListItem<T> *prev;

    ListItem(T theVal)
    {
       this->value = theVal;
       this->next = NULL;
       this->prev = NULL;
    }
};

template <class T>
List<T>::List()
{
    head=NULL;
}


template <class T>
List<T>::List(const List<T>& otherList)
{
     ListItem<T> *Headold=otherList.getHead();              
     if (Headold==NULL)
     {
        head=NULL;    //if otherlist head is NULL,new list head=0
     }
     else
     {           
         head=new ListItem<T>(Headold->value);    //initializing head to the string value

       //storing in temporary pointers
         ListItem<T> *oldnode=Headold;     
         ListItem<T> *newnode=head;
         while (temp->next!=NULL)
         {
            oldhead=oldhead->next;
            //making new node every instance 
            newnode->next=new ListItem<T>(oldhead->next->value); 
            ListItem<T> *newnodenext=newnode->next;
            newnodenext->prev=newnode;   //setting the previous pointer of the new node
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Why don't use use a debugger, and debug it ?

Comment: @Mellowcandle I am using Dev c++ and i am not familiar with its debugger.What I basically want to know is if I am making the copy of each node correctly or not.

Comment: It looks ok, but the purpose of stackoverflow is not to do code-reviews, if you encounter a specific error, or you want information regarding something specific ask it, general question like, look at this code, it's doesn't work, what's wrong with it are lousy questions...

Comment: @Mellowcandle I tried to debug and the error seems to be in initialization of linked list in which i set head pointer of linked list to NULL.is this a wrong way to do it?

Comment: Can we see the error or should we guess?

Comment: I am new to this forum so i don't know the correct way to ask the question so please forgive me if I am doing anything wrong

Comment: Begin with naming your variables better, how can I understand what's the difference between Head and head, or temp, temp1, temp2 ?

Comment: @Jueecy it is a segmentation fault

Answer (score 2):

You're not updating temp1, it stays all the time pointing the Head.
here's the fix.

```
  while (temp->next!=NULL)
     {
        temp=temp->next;
        //making new node every instance 
        temp1->next=new ListItem<T>(temp->next->value); 
        ListItem<T> *temp2=temp1->next;
        temp2->prev=temp1;   //setting the previous pointer of the new node
        temp1 = temp2;
     }
```

Comment: I  had a small mixup. fixed

Comment: Thanks for pointing out.Another thing that i asked was if the constructor is correct or not?could u please answer that.

Comment: Can it cause any problems in a linked list?